# Get OAuth Session Handle from Yahoo on iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, yahoo-api

I am trying to make an OAuth authentication to Yahoo Mail server and I tried using oauth.io and GMTOauth but neither of those do have the possibility to get the oauth_session_handle which an OAuth 1.0 authentication would return. I really need this so I can refresh my token. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take at a look at the new [Yahoo SDK for iOS](https://github.com/michaelchum/yos-social-objc) which supports OAuth1.0a and works with all Yahoo APIs

Comment: OMG thank you so much, mate! I was struggling with this for several weeks and now I finally solved it with your help. Thank you so much! I owe you a beer!

Comment: No worries :) Really glad it helped. This SDK was the product of a few weeks of work, I'm very happy you got good use of it!